# iPhone Provisioning: Is keychain is inserting wrong email address into the CSR?

Tags: iphone, email, provisioning, signing, keychain

I was having a problem where my Dev cert didn't expand (was not linked) to my private key.

I tracked the issue down to a discrepancy in the email used to create my Dev Cert and the one keychain was auto-selecting when I installed my CSR that I created to make my Dev cert.

I verified this by examining the contents of my CSR as follows.

1) Double click on the existing CSR file to start the 'install' process in Keychain.

2) Select the 'Let me override defaults for this request' checkbox.

3) Press Continue twice to get to the 'Create your certificate' page.

4) Select the 'Let me override defaults' checkbox.

5) Press Continue twice to get to the 'Certificate Information' page.

Here I found the email listed in the 'Email Address' field was different from the one I used to create the Dev Cert.

I tried to select the correct email and install the CSR, but I couldn't get the certs linked.

The only fix I could find was to recreate my Dev cert using that old email address so that when I installed the CSR in the normal way, everything was linked.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Does anyone know where keychain is getting that list of alternate email addresses, so I can clear it out?

Answer (score 1):

Getting the certificates to work right used to be a complete mess. I tried to follow Apple's original instructions last year and was never able to get it to work. Fortunately, there's a new way of doing it that is much simpler and more reliable:

1. log into the Apple iPhone Dev Center (http://developer.apple.com/iphone/)
2. click the link (right side of screen) to the **iPhone Developer Program Portal**
3. right in the middle of the page there is a new tool. The title text says "Get your application on an iPhone with the **Development Provisioning Assistant**" and there is a button marked "**launch assistant**". Click the button marked "launch assistant" and follow the instructions.

Result: Apple will lead you by the hand through the whole certification process, and it's completely different than it was before - your current issue might not even come up.